# java 8 interface default method return type not clear

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

recently i started reading about  java8 features,and one such feature i came across was

> default method

,there is nothing unique as far as concept is concerned,but i stumbled across this code snippet which used lambda expression for returning the value(void) from the default method.but i see that the return type of the default method is of the type *interface.*(which i believe should be void),since the logic inside the default method doesn't return anything ,Now i am puzzled by the behavior as i don't see any compilation error,But when  i set the type of the default method as void ,the compiler spouts(*The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*) error. Could someone explain about this behavior wrt to the lambda usage.

```
public interface Op {
void runOp();
static void timeOperation(Op testOp) {

}

 default Op combinedOp(Op secondOperation) {
    return ()->{secondOperation.runOp();};
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return void, it return a lambda expression

Comment: As a side note, the function you’re returning does not actually *combine* the ops, as it only evaluates the `secondOperation`, so it’s not different to just returning `secondOperation`. Perhaps, you want something like `return () -> { this.runOp(); secondOperation.runOp(); };`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write a lambda expression in a non-lambda way
with an anonymous class containing the implementation of the single abstract method.

Applied to your example, you can write the method

```
default Op combinedOp(Op secondOperation) {
    return ()->{secondOperation.runOp();};
}
```

in a non-lambda way like this:

```
default Op combinedOp(Op secondOperation) {
    return new Op() {
        @Override
        public void runOp() {
            secondOperation.runOp();
        }
    };
}
```

Now it is clearer to see that the `combinedOp` method returns something,
i.e. an instance of the `Op` interface.

However, the `runOp` method of this instance returns nothing.
Hence its return type is `void`.

Comment: Thanks,now I could see the above lambda expression through the lens. Much Appreciated!

Comment: one more way: `return secondOperation::runOp;`

Answer (score 3):

`Op` is a [functional interface](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces) i.e. an interface with a `SAM` (single abstract method).

The `combinedOp` is a default method which takes an `Op` as a parameter and returns an `Op` not *void*. In Java, functional interfaces can be used as target types for lambda expressions or method references hence the code below is completely valid:

```
default Op combinedOp(Op secondOperation) {
    return ()->{secondOperation.runOp();};
}
```

this code consumes an `Op` which then returns a function which when called upon will execute the `secondOperation` function.

Comment: Thanks ,but how this method implementation is different from the one where plain void type is mentioned as return type with no lambda usage. Has it got anything to do with lazy invocation.

Comment: @Sal a method as such `static void timeOperation(Op testOp) {
           testOp.runOp();
    }` consumes an `Op`  and excutes it, whereas a method as such `default Op combinedOp(Op secondOperation) {
    return ()->{secondOperation.runOp();};
}` consumes an `Op` and returns another function. it does not execute it.